# XFCE/lightdm startup configuration files

Tags: linux, xfce, debian-wheezy

Have recently installing Debian Wheezy and using XFCE 4.8.0.3 with lighdm.

After logging in with lightdm, my `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` are no longer sourced.
I have previously used these startup files to start ssh-agent, dropboxd and set my PATH variable.

If I understand this link (http://wiki.debian.org/DotFiles) correctly, when a display manager is in use (lightdm in this case). Then it is correct that these files do not get sourced.

So my questions are:
1) how can I make XFCE/lightdm source `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`
or
2) what are the equivalent startup configuration files of XFCE/lightdm to start ssh-agent, dropboxd and set my PATH variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK eventually found a workable solution and went with 2)

To set my PATH variable.
`$ cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc ~/.config/xfce4`
Then edited `~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc` to include the following near the top of the file

```
if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
fi
```

To start Dropbox when XFCE4 starts
`$ xfce4-settings-manager`
-> Session and Startup -> "Application Autostart" tab -> Add -> 
Name: Dropbox
Command: `/home/james/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`
-> OK

As for ssh-agent this gets started in the default xinitrc. (Can anyone recommend a GUI program to supply the passphrase)

Hope this is of assistance.

Comment: Copying and editing a file from `/etc/` smells. If the packages updates the original file your copy won't be updated. An alternative would be to copy no content but `exec /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` from your `~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc`right after your specific setup. Anyway I prefer the other `.profile`-based solution, which seems less specific to xfce or lightdm. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: GUI program to supply the passphrase: ssh-askpass-gnome, ssh-askpass, ssh-askpass-fullscreen. Also recommend GNU Keychain for keychain management.

Answer (score 10):

I've also struggled a lot with this environment variable thing.
I'm using Debian Jessie + xfce4

The options that worked for me are(for the environment variables to be caught by the desktop manager):

- With xdm or lightdm: use `~/.xsessionrc`
- With others, I haven't tested

In the `~/.xsessionrc` you may chose to :

- put directly the variables, like `PATH="$PATH:userpath"`
- or source the `~/.profile` file: `. $HOME/.profile`, where the `~/.profile` file contains the environment variables definitions

Note the dot in the second option which means `source`, but I think `source` is bash specific.
The second method is probably recommended (as argued in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/correctly-setting-environment) and avoid having the environment variables defined in several files. Also, it's user-specific and not system-wide like (`/etc/environment`, which actually didn't work so well for me)

For terminal session, since I use `bash`, I set-up the environment variables in the `.bash_profile` or I just source the `~/.profile`

Comment: Thanks alot ! Finally! I had to search alot to find this easy solution. One thing to mention: If the file ~/.xsessionrc does not exist, just create it !

Comment: At first in `~/.xsessionrc` I put `. ~/.profile` and it did not work. As stated in this answer if the content is `. $HOME/.profile` then it works.

Comment: What I find to be **important**: `~/.xsessionrc` is executed by plain `/bin/sh`, so the script needs to be POSIX compliant. See an [example here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708372/22339).